# C# Equivalent of SQL Server DataTypes

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

For the following SQL Server datatypes, what would be the corresponding datatype in C#?

**Exact Numerics**

```
bigint
numeric
bit
smallint
decimal
smallmoney
int
tinyint
money
```

---

**Approximate Numerics**

```
float
real
```

---

**Date and Time**

```
date
datetimeoffset
datetime2
smalldatetime
datetime
time
```

---

**Character Strings**

```
char
varchar
text
```

---

**Unicode Character Strings**

```
nchar
nvarchar
ntext
```

---

**Binary Strings**

```
binary
varbinary
image
```

---

**Other Data Types**

```
cursor
timestamp
hierarchyid
uniqueidentifier
sql_variant
xml
table
```

(source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx))

Comment: I think this is what you might be looking for: [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)

Answer (score 1335, accepted):

This is for [SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092(SQL.90).aspx). There are updated versions of the table for [SQL Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), [SQL Server 2008 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and [SQL Server 2014](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092(v=sql.120).aspx).

### SQL Server Data Types and Their .NET Framework Equivalents

The following table lists Microsoft SQL Server data types, their equivalents in the common language runtime (CLR) for SQL Server in the **System.Data.SqlTypes** namespace, and their native CLR equivalents in the Microsoft .NET Framework.

| SQL Server data type | CLR data type (SQL Server) | CLR data type (.NET Framework) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| varbinary | SqlBytes, SqlBinary | Byte[] |
| binary | SqlBytes, SqlBinary | Byte[] |
| varbinary(1), binary(1) | SqlBytes, SqlBinary | byte, Byte[] |
| image | None | None |
| varchar | None | None |
| char | None | None |
| nvarchar(1), nchar(1) | SqlChars, SqlString | Char, String, Char[] |
| nvarchar | SqlChars, SqlString | String, Char[] |
| nchar | SqlChars, SqlString | String, Char[] |
| text | None | None |
| ntext | None | None |
| uniqueidentifier | SqlGuid | Guid |
| rowversion | None | Byte[] |
| bit | SqlBoolean | Boolean |
| tinyint | SqlByte | Byte |
| smallint | SqlInt16 | Int16 |
| int | SqlInt32 | Int32 |
| bigint | SqlInt64 | Int64 |
| smallmoney | SqlMoney | Decimal |
| money | SqlMoney | Decimal |
| numeric | SqlDecimal | Decimal |
| decimal | SqlDecimal | Decimal |
| real | SqlSingle | Single |
| float | SqlDouble | Double |
| smalldatetime | SqlDateTime | DateTime |
| datetime | SqlDateTime | DateTime |
| sql_variant | None | Object |
| User-defined type(UDT) | None | user-defined type |
| table | None | None |
| cursor | None | None |
| timestamp | None | None |
| xml | SqlXml | None |

Comment: Which CLR data type (SQL Server) should be used for `short` in .Net framework ?

Comment: @yogeshpatel, `short` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/short) is equal to System.Int16 in this listing. So that would be smallint in SQL Server.

Comment: Important note: SQL data type "float" defaults to "float(54)" which converts to C# "double".
HOWEVER, SQL datatype "float(24)" converts to C# "float" only. 
So if you don't need many digits of precision and want to improve performance/memory, use float(24) in SQL and types "float" in C#.

Answer (score 98):

SQL Server and .Net Data Type mapping

[image: SQL Server and .Net Data Type mapping]

Answer (score 19):

In case anybody is looking for methods to convert from/to C# and SQL Server formats, here goes a simple implementation:

```
private readonly string[] SqlServerTypes = { "bigint", "binary", "bit",  "char", "date",     "datetime", "datetime2", "datetimeoffset", "decimal", "filestream", "float",  "geography",                              "geometry",                              "hierarchyid",                              "image",  "int", "money",   "nchar",  "ntext",  "numeric", "nvarchar", "real",   "rowversion", "smalldatetime", "smallint", "smallmoney", "sql_variant", "text",   "time",     "timestamp", "tinyint", "uniqueidentifier", "varbinary", "varchar", "xml" };
private readonly string[] CSharpTypes    = { "long",   "byte[]", "bool", "char", "DateTime", "DateTime", "DateTime",  "DateTimeOffset", "decimal", "byte[]",     "double", "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography", "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeometry", "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlHierarchyId", "byte[]", "int", "decimal", "string", "string", "decimal", "string",   "Single", "byte[]",     "DateTime",      "short",    "decimal",    "object",      "string", "TimeSpan", "byte[]",    "byte",    "Guid",             "byte[]",    "string",  "string" };

public string ConvertSqlServerFormatToCSharp(string typeName)
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(SqlServerTypes, typeName);

    return index > -1
        ? CSharpTypes[index]
        : "object";
}

public string ConvertCSharpFormatToSqlServer(string typeName)
{
    var index = Array.IndexOf(CSharpTypes, typeName);

    return index > -1
        ? SqlServerTypes[index]
        : null;
}
```

Edit: fixed typo

Comment: Your method ConvertCSharpFormatToSqlServer will only always return the first instance found as CSharp Types are not unique, i.e. "byte[]" will always return "binary" even though it's mapped to 5 other Sql Server Types.

Comment: @David although what you said is not technicaly wrong, it makes sense when you are using the `ConvertSqlServerFormatToCSharp` method. This is just an example, you can always modify it for your own needs.

Answer (score 8):

SQL Server and the .NET Framework are based on different type systems. For example, the .NET Framework Decimal structure has a maximum scale of 28, whereas the SQL Server decimal and numeric data types have a maximum scale of 38. Click Here's [a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)! for detail

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7):

```
public static string FromSqlType(string sqlTypeString)
{
    if (! Enum.TryParse(sqlTypeString, out Enums.SQLType typeCode))
    {
        throw new Exception("sql type not found");
    }
    switch (typeCode)
    {
        case Enums.SQLType.varbinary:
        case Enums.SQLType.binary:
        case Enums.SQLType.filestream:
        case Enums.SQLType.image:
        case Enums.SQLType.rowversion:
        case Enums.SQLType.timestamp://?
            return "byte[]";
        case Enums.SQLType.tinyint:
            return "byte";
        case Enums.SQLType.varchar:
        case Enums.SQLType.nvarchar:
        case Enums.SQLType.nchar:
        case Enums.SQLType.text:
        case Enums.SQLType.ntext:
        case Enums.SQLType.xml:
            return "string";
        case Enums.SQLType.@char:
            return "char";
        case Enums.SQLType.bigint:
            return "long";
        case Enums.SQLType.bit:
            return "bool";
        case Enums.SQLType.smalldatetime:
        case Enums.SQLType.datetime:
        case Enums.SQLType.date:
        case Enums.SQLType.datetime2:
            return "DateTime";
        case Enums.SQLType.datetimeoffset:
            return "DateTimeOffset";
        case Enums.SQLType.@decimal:
        case Enums.SQLType.money:
        case Enums.SQLType.numeric:
        case Enums.SQLType.smallmoney:
            return "decimal";
        case Enums.SQLType.@float:
            return "double";
        case Enums.SQLType.@int:
            return "int";
        case Enums.SQLType.real:
            return "Single";
        case Enums.SQLType.smallint:
            return "short";
        case Enums.SQLType.uniqueidentifier:
            return "Guid";
        case Enums.SQLType.sql_variant:
            return "object";
        case Enums.SQLType.time:
            return "TimeSpan";
        default:
            throw new Exception("none equal type");
    }
}

public enum SQLType
{
    varbinary,//(1)
    binary,//(1)
    image,
    varchar,
    @char,
    nvarchar,//(1)
    nchar,//(1)
    text,
    ntext,
    uniqueidentifier,
    rowversion,
    bit,
    tinyint,
    smallint,
    @int,
    bigint,
    smallmoney,
    money,
    numeric,
    @decimal,
    real,
    @float,
    smalldatetime,
    datetime,
    sql_variant,
    table,
    cursor,
    timestamp,
    xml,
    date,
    datetime2,
    datetimeoffset,
    filestream,
    time,
}
```