# DateTime Insert via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datetime

I have a column in my table which has a DataType of 'timestamp'. Now I am inserting a row through LINQ2SQL. Now what should I write here:

```
Entity_Product_Point ev = new Entity_Product_Point();
ev.DateCreated = ???
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean SQL server `timestamp`? That really has very little to do with time...

Comment: So what should be the datatype if I want the time and date to be inserted?

Comment: You **cannot** insert a value for this field.  See my answer

Comment: NET-SLUT (fun to type!), you want DateTime as mentioned below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you SURE you wanted [timestamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)?  It has nothing to do with dates...  If you'd like to store "DateCreated", I think you probably want to use either a `DateTime` or just `Date` datatype in MSSQL.  If that's what you really intended, then you can pass in `DateTime.Now` for a value.

Comment: easiest +4 you'll ever get hah

Answer (score 2):

Well the corresponding type would be `byte[]`, but this type is used internally by SQL Server for row versioning—and by ORMs for optimistic locking.  You should never (can't) write a value out for a timestamp column manually.

For a more complete listing of which type correspond to what, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-equivalent-of-sql-server-2005-datatypes)