# What does a timestamp in T-Sql mean in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, db2

I'm trying to develop a model object to hold a Sql Server row, and I understand perfectly how to do this except for the T-Sql/SqlServer timestamp.  The table is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE activity (
activity_id int
, ip_address varchar(39)
, user_id varchar(255)
, message_text
, dt timestamp
)
```

When I resolve a table row to my object, for an int or a string I would expect to do something like:

```
ActivityID = (int)dataReader["activity_id"];
IPAddress = (string)dataReader["ip_address"];
```

But what do I do about the timestamp column?  There's no "timestamp" datatype that I can find anywhere.  I know that Sql Server stores timestamp as an 8 byte binary, but what is this normally the equivalent of in .NET?

**Edited to add:** A little extra information... this is a row being returned from a DB2 table on our mainframe coming through a Sql Server view.  "Rowversion" isn't an option, and DB2 is handing the column off as a timestamp.  If timestamp and rowversion are identical, maybe I can treat it as one, but otherwise I'm stuck with timestamp.

**Edited again to add:** This project is going to drive me nuts.  It will, at least, be a short trip.  Anyway, yes @JoelC this is a Sql Server view into a DB2 database on the mainframe.  I was finally able to track down one of our DBAs, who explained disdainfully that "of course" a DB2 TIMESTAMP comes across as to a Sql Server view as a datetime.  From his tone of voice I guess only noobs don't know this.  That's why he named it "datetime" in the actual view, Duh! (I gave it a different name in my example so as to not trigger commentary on naming conventions -- the actual data model diagram says it's a TIMESTAMP and names it timestamp).  So, in this event, apparently one must cast it to a DateTime.  I think I may begin considering becoming a DBA so that I, too, can drive programmers crazy.  Sorry if I misled any of the responders to this question -- it was unintentional, as I was actually expecting a timestamp to be, well, a timestamp.  Silly me.  Thanks are especially due to Microsoft for naming a byte-array datatype a "timestamp" when it has nothing to do with dates and times.  I haven't the vaguest idea which response to mark as the Answer. Sigh.

Comment: @Michael that's not what OP asked. I would use DateTime, BTW

Comment: What about `DateTime` object, it can hold your timestamp.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-equivalent-of-sql-server-2005-datatypes

Comment: You should be using `rowversion` instead of `timestamp` - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx

Comment: That's great advice if I have control over the database, which I don't.  This is actually a DB2 table coming through a Sql Server view.

Comment: @Cyber How are you bringing the DB2 database into SQL? Can you change the data type on the column in the view? I don't think a DB2 timestamp should map to a SQL Server timestamp, they don't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The name of the Sql Server timestamp data type is confusing.  It's really better to think of it more like a version number — there's no date/time information in there anywhere.  In fact, as of Sql Server 2008 the type was renamed to "rowversion".

Most of the time you want the `datetime` type in Sql Server instead, which maps easily to DateTime in C#, or perhaps [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) if you have a version so Sql Server that supports it.  Documentation on the timestamp type is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.90).aspx

If you really must map that timestamp column as-is, the closest match is probably plain old `long` (or maybe ulong), but I have no idea how sql server handles byte ordering or big/little endien-ness vs C#.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer, because it is the correct answer in response to what I thought was the question.  The question having become different because my underlying assumption was wrong, the answers saying to cast to DateTime are correct in that instance.

Answer (score 20):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/0ad05e31-c3b2-44fb-99f5-32e80754e37a/)

you'll have to cast it to a byte array.

```
byte[] dt = dataReader["dt"] as byte[];
```

Answer (score 11):

It's a `byte[]`, with a `Length` of `8`.

Answer (score 6):

when retrieving from database

```
string dt = Convert.ToBase64String(dataReader["dt"] as byte[]);
```

when passing into database

```
new SqlParameter("@dt", Convert.FromBase64String(dt))
```