# SQL Timestamp to datetime on C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net-core

I have the following column on my `SQL` table:

```
RECORDTIMESTAMP
0x000000000005B2A4
0x000000000005B2A5
0x000000000005B2A6
```

And I need to return this values on my C# program. This atributte is declared like this:

```
public DateTime? RecordTimeStamp{ get; set; }
```

And my method to get is this one:

```
RecordTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(row["RecordTimeStamp"].ToString()),
```

The error message is the following:

```
  "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.",
```

I also tried to declare the atribbute as string but it didn't worked also.

Any Ideas on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a timestamp in T-Sql mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334777/what-does-a-timestamp-in-t-sql-mean-in-c)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A common misconeption here: `Timestamp` is not actual a time.

It was a miss-naming. That is why it was renamed to `ROWVERSION` half a dozen versions ago. `Timestamp` was only still used as Alias, with a clear "deprecated" marker. From
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql:

> `timestamp` is the synonym for the `rowversion` data type and is subject to the behavior of data type synonyms. In DDL statements, use `rowversion` instead of `timestamp` wherever possible. For more information, see [Data Type Synonyms (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-synonyms-transact-sql).
>
> The Transact-SQL `timestamp` data type is different from the `timestamp` data type defined in the ISO standard.
>
> **Note**
>
> The `timestamp` syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Comment: re the SQL Server specific bits: OP actually tagged the question as [tag:mysql]; mis-taggings happen, of course, so this context is probably good

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a rowversion column (which has historically been called a "timestamp" column, despite it not being a stamp of the time). A rowversion is not a time - it is just an opaque monotonically incrementing integer that means nothing other than it lets you spot that a change has happened. Timestamps are often used for optimistic concurrency checking, but have no actual meaning. Depending on the size, a `long`, or a `byte[]` or a `string` might be fine for storage.