# What datatype in C# should I use if mapping a database column of type Timestamp?

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, sql-server-2017

My client is using [Insight.Database](https://github.com/jonwagner/Insight.Database) for SQL Server ORM, using C# as the client.  I have encountered a SQL Server 2017 database datatype 'Timestamp' and I am unsure what the C# entity type should be?  I have downloaded the code for the Insight.Database and have globally searched for Timestamp, but results are empty.

Any ideas what datatype in C# would best represent a SQL Server Timestamp datatype?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334777/what-does-a-timestamp-in-t-sql-mean-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a byte array as that's what you'd use for varbinary.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings