# What will be datatype for SQL timestamp in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

What will be the equivalent data type for Timestamp in C#? If I want to retrieve data from SQL server and want to map with C# object?

Comment: Just to be clear you know that Timestamp is not an actual time stamp and holds no date time information ? its used for row versioning, and can be converted to `byte[8]`

Comment: "Timestamp" is very confusing, as documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6334777/what-does-a-timestamp-in-t-sql-mean-in-c) on Stack Overflow

Comment: @MichaelRandall,
I know Timestamp is using for row versioning but what if we want to map with C# model ?

Comment: "DateTime" will get you you the date with time "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt"

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Timestamp data type is very confusing. It's more like a version number and holds no date/ time information and as of SQL Server 2008 was renamed to "rowversion". That being said if you really need to map "timestamp" column the best match is probably just a plain old `long` (or `ulong` depending on how SQL Server treats big/ little endianess)

If you want a DateTime equivalent you'll want to use the `datetime` type in SQL Server instead, which maps directly and easily to `DateTime` in C#.

Comment: This answer looks like a carbon copy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/6334815/11683 with some bits slightly rearranged.

Answer (score -1):

When mapping the c# object, you might want to declare a property with either ***byte[]*** or ***long***.

Hope this helps.