# error when inserting C#'s decimal into SQL numeric

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, sqldatatypes

i'm using SQL server 2008 and have a table with a field type of numeric(7,3), into which i want to insert values using a C# web-service (i know that values won't be more than 4 digits before the decimal and 3 digits afterwards).  therefore my C# variable is of type decimal (as i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-2005-datatypes)).
it basically looks like this -

```
SqlParameter vsp = new SqlParameter("@VideoStartPoint", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    vsp.Scale = 3;
                    vsp.Precision = 7;
                    vsp.Value = VideoStartPoint;
```

however, i found out that it works **only** if the value is less than 10.  for any value from 10 and above i get an error - "*Error converting data type numeric to numeric*".
i know there's no problem in my table, for when i insert it using SQL i have no problem with >10 values.

any ideas?
cheers,
eRez

Comment: does it work if you do not specify scale and precision?

Comment: Can you show us your stored procedure/sql that you employed here?

Comment: Did you by chance swallow *Arithmetic overflow error .....*, Is the `VideoStartPoint` pointing to the column in question (7,3) or if a stored proc then whats the corresponding datatype

Comment: no - i doesn't work if a don't specify the scale and precision (i added them after reading some advice here, but it made no change); that's my testing SQL (which works): INSERT INTO [Statistics].[dbo].[VideoStatsAuditEvent]
           ([EntryDateTime]
           ,[VideoSessionID]
           ,[VideoID]
           ,[VideoActionID]
           ,[videoStartPoint])
     VALUES
           (GETDATE()
           ,'F02689A1-4A0A-4437-BEBD-DE9E94F68656'
           ,96238
           ,54          
           ,11.1234)
GO; @V4Vendetta - not sure if i understand what you meant

Comment: 11.1234 seems to have more than 3 digits after the decimal point. A better piece of test SQL would be to create a variable of type `decimal(7,3)`, assign the test value to that variable, and then use it in the insert statement

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - you're correct, but that was just some testing code i used, and as i mentioned - it had no problem (only cut that last '4' digit).  this piece of code also have no problem - DECLARE @t numeric(7,3)
SET @t = 78.123;SELECT @t

Comment: @eRez - what is the datatype of the VideoStartPoint field in your VideoStatsAuditEvent table? Can you also post the full stack trace and any inner exceptions from your error handler?

Answer (score 1):

If the  VideoStartPoint is a string and your locale uses '.' instead of ',' as a thousand separator , the value '11.1234' will be translated as 11123.000 as .NET will use your thread's locale value to convert the string to a decimal.
This can happen in French, Italian, Greek locales, I think Spanish as well.

You should place a breakpoint to check the value of VideoStartPoint even if it is a decimal. There may be a problem at the client's side that is improperly converting a numeric string to decimal.

**EDIT:**
To illustrate, the following code parses the same string "11.450" with two different locales, Greek and US, resulting in two different numbers, 11450 and 11.450

```
        var grNumber = decimal.Parse("123.450", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("el-GR"));
        var usNumber = decimal.Parse("123.450", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
        Debug.Assert(grNumber == 123450);
        Debug.Assert(usNumber == (decimal) 123.45);
```

The following LINQ statement returns all cultures that use '.' as their thousand separator:

```
        var cultures = (from culture in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                       where culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator == "."
                       select culture.Name);
```

There are 92 different cultures corresponding to 33 ISO languages (CultureInfo.TwoLetterISOLanguageName), including Spain, Netherlands, Belgium, Germany etc.

Comment: thanks, but i don't think this is the issue.  VideoStartPoint is decimal, and i read it like this -  decimal VideoStartPoint = 0;
 if (!decimal.TryParse(requestCollection["VideoStartPoint"], out VideoStartPoint))
{
      VideoStartPoint = 0;
}
besides - had that been the reason, correct me if i wrong but it should have also happened on decimals less than 10 as well

Comment: No, .NET (and VBA before this) simply ignore a misplaced thousands separator. They will only fail when they encounter a misplaced decimal separator. 11.000 in one of those locales will be translated to 11000 while 11,000,000 will raise an exception.

Decimal.TryParse would still succeed if requestCollection["VideoStartPoint"] contains what (to your locale) is a thousand separator. 

What is the value contained in requestCollection["VideoStartPoint"]?

Comment: for example "11.123" (that will fail, while "1.123" won't).  in any case, i don't send any thousands separator what so eve

Comment: I didn't say that you are using thousand separators, just that your locale may be translating '.' as a thousand separator. Check the edit for code that illustrates this and a query to return all locales that use '.' as a thousand separator