# "Specified cast is not valid" when a null value is returned as Nullable<int>

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

In my SQL Database I have a following view:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS
(SELECT ChangeType FROM MyTable) UNION ALL
(SELECT NULL AS ChangeType FROM MyTable)
```

where `ChangeType` has type `TINYINT`. Then in my C# code I have a following class:

```
[Table(Name = "MyView")]
public class MyView
{
    [Column]
    public Nullable<int> ChangeType;
}
```

which is used as follows:

```
var table = dataContext.GetTable<MyView>();
var elements = table.ToArray();
```

and when this code runs I get the following exception:

```
[InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +6393860
Read_MyView(ObjectMaterializer`1 ) +3404
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext() +42
System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source) +488
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1 source) +104
MyCodeHere
```

If I change the second part of `UNION` as follows:

```
(SELECT CONVERT(INT,NULL) AS ChangeType FROM MyTable)
```

the same code runs just fine.

Why does that "cast is not valid" there? Why won't the `TINYINT` just be read in place of `int`?

Comment: See this article: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-2005-datatypes>

TinyInt maps to Byte in the CLR

Comment: See this article: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-2005-datatypes>

TinyInt maps to Byte in the CLR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why won't the TINYINT just be read in place of int?

Because `TINYINT` maps to either `short` or `sbyte`.

Edit: [Looked it up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and it's an unsigned byte, so use `byte`.

```
[Column]
public Nullable<byte> ChangeType;
```

Your stack-trace shows that the the Linq2Sql mapper calls `.get_Int32()`. Assuming this is similar to [`SqlDataReader.GetInt32()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32.aspx) then that means it will attempt to read a 32 bit value, no conversions are applied.

Comment: Anyway, tinyint fits into int just okay, why the exception?

Comment: Yes, you can (implicitly) convert a `byte` valueto an `int`. But you cannot call `GetInt32()` on a Byte-sized column. Stricter rules.

Comment: Great, could you please include the last bit into the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
[Column]
    public Nullable<Int32> ChangeType; //for int type
    public Nullable<Int16> ChangeType; //for smallint type
```