# ASP.NET c# Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to get single value from select query called tenant. Tenant_Facing from SQL Server have single char value that either 'Y' or 'N'. When I execute it, there a error that say "Specified cast is not valid" on Char tenant = (Char)cmd.ExecuteScalar();.
I don't understand why it not match even they are both Char? Here my codes,

```
protected void DropDownArchitecture_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database_Shared_NotebookConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        string architecture = ((DropDownList)GridViewServer.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownArchitecture")).Text;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Tenant_Facing FROM tblArchitecture WHERE Architecture = '" + architecture + "'");

        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();

        Char tenant = (Char)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        conn.Close();

        if (tenant == 'Y')
        {
            ((DropDownList)GridViewServer.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownTenant")).Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ((DropDownList)GridViewServer.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownTenant")).Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried casting it to a string? string tenant = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: A little advice: Use boolean instead Y or N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though your data type in SQL Server is a single `char`, that type still maps to `string` in ADO.NET. Try it like this instead:

```
string tenant = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

conn.Close();

if (tenant == "Y")
//            ^ ^ make sure to change these to double-quotes
{
    ((DropDownList)GridViewServer.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownTenant")).Visible = true;
}
else
{
    ((DropDownList)GridViewServer.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownTenant")).Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank! It work and kinda strange when it still maps to string

Answer (score 1):

According to this post ( [C# Equivalent of SQL Server DataTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-2005-datatypes) ), there is no C# CLR equivalent of a MSSQL char.  Your best bet is to do:

```
Char tenant = Convert.ToChar(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the return value is of a different type. I'd say it may be a string, but to be sure, try storing the original result of `ExecuteScalar` in a separate variable and use debugger to determine its CLR type.

Answer (score 0):

`Sql Char` is equal to `C sharp string`.

```
String tenant = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); //Or
String tenant = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```