# Dapper error parsing tinyint to short?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-4.0, dapper

The column in SQL Server 2008 is `[tinyint] NULL`

The property on the class in C# is `short?`

I am just doing a simple select query.

In Dapper .NET 3.5 it worked perfectly.

I recently updated to .NET 4.0, and to Dapper .NET 4.0, but now I get the following DataException:

> {"Error parsing column 3 (COLUMNNAME=30 - Byte)"}

InnerException:

> {"Invalid cast from 'System.Byte' to 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int16, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'."}

Any ideas why this is trying to convert as a byte?

EDIT: If I change the property to `short` it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. If I change the property of `Byte?` it works fine.

This answer seems to suggest it is the correct type to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/968734/1061602