# What is bit data type equivalent in DBML?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, sqldatatypes, dbml

I'm mapping a column in a DBML to a bit column in SQL Server.  Which of the following should "Type" (not server data type) in the DBML be marked as:

- Binary (System.Data.Linq.Binary)
- boolean
- byte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx, for **bit** on MSSQL

"The string values TRUE and FALSE can be converted to bit values: TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0."

Going by that logic, I would use **boolean** for your mapping.

NOTE: *This is a pretty commonly discussed question on forums, including stack overflow. I'm certain there is a more comprehensive answer available.*

I found a more comprehensive answer:
[C# Equivalent of SQL Server DataTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes)