# C# alternative data types

Tags: c#, sql

I was given SQL sever database to rebuild a website for someone it has these data types:

- money
- bit

I am currently creating an MVC model and the data types are not recognized in MVC

```
   public class Beds
    {

        public int BedID { get; set; }    
        public Bit  Private { get; set; }  <------not recognized
        public Money OccupiedRate { get; set; }  <------not recognized
        public Bit HoldingRate { get; set; }    <------not recognized

    }
```

What are the best alternative datatypes in MVC?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use (`Boolean`) instead of (`Bit`) and use (`Decimal`) instead of (`Money`). [see](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d496c385-e0d9-4b98-81a4-1181270ea030/sql-server-vs-c-data-types)

Answer (score 1):

Your datatype mappings are dependent on the language (C#), not the framework (MVC).

In your case the mappings are:

- `Bit` is `Boolean`
- `Money` is `Decimal`

For a full list of conversion types [see this list on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.100).aspx). The C# column is headed **.NET Framework type**