# LINQ Specified Cast is Not Valid with a ushort Table Column

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying get the max value of a `ushort` type column from a `DataTable`.

It throws up `"Specified Cast is Not Valid"`

Here is the query

```
var c = DSFinyr.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Max(p => p.Field<ushort>("finid"));
```

tried with `int` also. same error.

How do i cast this ?

thanks

Comment: Nor in this case. But may be in future.

Comment: Are all the values in the "finid" column actually `ushort` or `int`?

Comment: they are ushort. It is smallint field in SqlServer.

Comment: The 'u' in ushort means Unsigned.  Meaning it can't have negative values.  That is not the same as smallint in sql server.  smallint is equivalent to Int16 in .NET.

Comment: ExecuteDataset returned this table and when i go to row and expand members then the type shown is ushort !

Comment: Try it with Int16 and see what happens.

Comment: @Jim Int16 worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent to SQL Server `smallint` in c# is `short`, not `ushort`. And if the field is nullable, then you need to use `short?` like this:

```
var c = DSFinyr.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Max(p => p.Field<short?>("finid"));
```

Comment: The equivalent to SMALLINT is Int16, not int or short.  Not that it matters that much, you can cast an Int16 to an int or short.

Comment: See this for SQL Server to .NET equavalents...   http://stackoverflow.com/a/968734/1246574

Comment: as i have said the value in the field is numeric 1. It is a not null.

Comment: @jim, but `short` is `int16`. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx).

Comment: @Deb, You did not say it is Numeric, you said SMALLINT.  You said it right in the comments on your OP.

Comment: @Deb It doesn't matter what the value is. If today's value is not null, you may have a null in the future. The important thing is the type of the field. If it is nullable, then you need to use the nullable type in C#.

Comment: By Numeric i mean number (Not Character) . Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @RacilHilan The Column Type shows Int16, But when you check Row data members it is ushort. Thanks anyway. Upvoted.

Comment: @Deb Yes, the Column Type is what matters, not the raw data. So you can use `Int16` or `short`. Both are equivalent in C#.