# How to convert smallmoney to something c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012

I have database column as "Salary". I'm keeping salary records of employees in this column as smallMoney. With C# I can insert this column value like "2000". After that I saw that columns value is "2000,00" in database. I need to get this value back like "2000" as string to update in my program. Because my program works like this. So, to use this value again, how can I convert this smallMoney to something to use effectively for my program? (Int "2000" or String "2000" is ok for my program)

I researched but couldn't find solution. Could anyone say how I do this?

Comment: There is a very thorough answer to that question here. [C#-SQL Server data types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes)

Comment: Try to add code like this in app_start, hope this will help ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());

Comment: As it's your program, you do not really *need* the value as a string. You can accept any input and [convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) it internally whatever way you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SQL `smallmoney` is equal to a C# `decimal`.
So after retrieving it from the database, you could convert it to an `int`. (*You will lose the any decimal numbers though*)  OR you may use string formatting to only show the whole numbers.

For example:

```
// Create example value from database
decimal dSalary = 2000.00m;

int iSalary = Convert.ToInt32(dSalary);
```

Or you could keep it a decimal and just use string formatting, like this:

```
string Result = dSalary.ToString("0");
```