# Read from datatable different types

Tags: c#

```
   if (_dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in _dt.Rows)
                {
                    pUsername = row["tUsername"] == DBNull.Value ? " " : row["tUsername"].ToString();
                    pDomain = row["tDomain"] == DBNull.Value ? " " : row["tDomain"].ToString();
                    pStatus = row["tStatus"] == DBNull.Value ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(row["tStatus"].ToString());
                    // pAdmin = (bool)row["tInstallType"];
                }
            }
```

How can i read different types from datatable ?Do i have to go each time to string ? . Why can't i read as type integer from database ? I think the main problem is `row["tStatus"].ToString()`

Comment: Oh, and **thank you** for questioning that `Convert.ToInt32(row["myInt"].ToString())` madness. Too many novice developers just copy that style from bad Internet tutorials and books without realizing that it is just plain *wrong*.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* read integers directly from the data table:

```
int myInt = row.Field<int>("myInt");

int? myNullableInt = row.Field<int?>("myNullableInt");  // NULL (DB) -> null (C#)

int myInt = row.Field<int?>("myNullableInt") ?? 0;      // NULL (DB) -> 0 (C#)
```

This uses the new [DataRowExtensions.Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) method introduced with .net 3.5. Obviously, this is not restricted to `int`s but works for all primitive C# types and their nullable counterparts. Note that, contrary to the indexer, `Field` returns `null` for database NULL values rather than DBNull.Value.

Comment: That compared with this is win "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes"

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic extension method [DataRow.Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.field(v=vs.90).aspx), so in your example for pUsername you could do:

```
string pUsername = row.Field<string>( "tUsername" );
```

and

```
int? pStatus = row.Field<int?>("tStatus")
```

Which are imo, much cleaner as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) language extension methods for DataRow.

Example

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}",row.Field<string>("FirstName"), row.Field<int?>("SomeIntField"));
}
```