# Converting data types from Oracle to SQL Server in an ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oracle

I'm working on the database migration of an ASP.NET project (from Oracle to SQL Server) and part of this work if to modify a connection helper class.

This class contains in particular a piece of code that performs a matching between C# variable types and members of the OracleDbType enum. So I have to transform this matching into a matching between C# variable types and members of the SqlDbType enum.

The first approach I used to do that was to transform a member of the OracleDbType into a member of the SqlDbType using the following steps:

-Find the Oracle SQL type matching the  OracleDbType member using this table in [Oracle's official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/OracleDbTypeEnumerationType.htm)

-Find the corresponding Sql Server data type using this table in [microsoft's official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/non-sql/data-type-mapping-for-oracle-publishers)

-Find the corresponding SqlDbType enum member using this table in [microsoft's official documenation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx)

However this approach led me to some problems. For example, in my original code, there is a distinction between a 'short' variable (translated into OracleDbType.Int16) and an 'int' variable (translated into OracleDbType.Int32). Using the method I described above, I have to transform both OracleDbType.Int16 and OracleDbType.Int32 into SqlDbType.Decimal which is weird and doesn't seem correct.

So I have chosen to only use [this table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) and focus on the columns '.NET Framework type' and 'SqlDbType enumeration' to do the transformation, which leads to transform OracleDbType.Int16 into SqlDbType.SmallInt and OracleDbType.Int32 into SqlDbType.BigInt.

I would like to know which one of my methods is correct and why.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but maybe I can help you shed some light on this. One of your assumptions in your question that is wrong is that a OracleDbType.Int32 is a BigInt in SQLServer. is is actually a SqlDbType.Int. OracleDbType.Int64 is a SqlDbType.BigInt. So If I have to create a comparing table of the types of Oracle to Framework to SqlServer I would put it like this.

```
Oracle          .Net Type       SqlServerType
BFile           byte[]          varbinary(max) With FileStream
Blob            byte[]          varbinary
Byte            byte            tinyint
Char            Char/String     char
Clob            String          varchar(max)
Date            DateTime        Date
Decimal         decimal         decimal/numeric
Double          double          float
Int16           Int16           smallint
Int32           int             int
Int64           long/Int64      bigint
Long            String          (n)varchar(max)
LongRaw         byte[]          varbinary(max)
NChar           String          nchar
NClob           String          nvarchar
NVarchar2       String          nvarchar
Raw             byte[]          varbinary
Single          single          real
TimeStamp       DateTime        datetime2
TimeStampLTZ    DateTime        datetimeoffset (i think)
TimeStampTZ     DateTime        datetimeoffset
Varchar2        String          varchar
XmlType         String          XML
```

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes) link that also provide the CLR types.

In my opinion I would create a dictionary for your transformations which links a OracleDbType to a SqlDbType etc. I have a similar dictionary that I use between SqlDbTypes and .Net types.

```
public static Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType> typeMap = 
    new Dictionary<Type, SqlDbType>() 
{ 
    { typeof(byte), SqlDbType.TinyInt}, { typeof(sbyte), SqlDbType.TinyInt },
    { typeof(short), SqlDbType.SmallInt}, { typeof(ushort), SqlDbType.SmallInt },
    { typeof(int), SqlDbType.Int }, {typeof(uint), SqlDbType.Int },
    { typeof(long), SqlDbType.BigInt },   {typeof(ulong), SqlDbType.BigInt },               
    { typeof(float), SqlDbType.Float }, { typeof(double), SqlDbType.Float },
    { typeof(decimal), SqlDbType.Decimal }, {typeof(bool),  SqlDbType.Bit },
    { typeof(string), SqlDbType.VarChar },  {typeof(char), SqlDbType.Char },
    { typeof(Guid),  SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier }, { typeof(DateTime), SqlDbType.DateTime}, 
    { typeof(DateTimeOffset), SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset }, { typeof(byte[]), SqlDbType.VarBinary },
    //Nullable fields
    { typeof(byte?), SqlDbType.TinyInt }, { typeof(sbyte?), SqlDbType.TinyInt },  
    { typeof(short?), SqlDbType.SmallInt}, { typeof(ushort?), SqlDbType.SmallInt }, 
    { typeof(int?), SqlDbType.Int }, { typeof(uint?), SqlDbType.Int }, 
    { typeof(long?), SqlDbType.BigInt }, { typeof(ulong?), SqlDbType.BigInt },
    { typeof(float?), SqlDbType.Float }, { typeof(double?), SqlDbType.Float },
    { typeof(decimal?), SqlDbType.Decimal}, { typeof(bool?), SqlDbType.Bit },
    { typeof(Guid?), SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier}, { typeof(DateTime?), SqlDbType.DateTime },
    { typeof(DateTimeOffset?), SqlDbType.DateTimeOffset }
};
```

Hope this helps.