# Does a byte data type exist or is there an equivalent in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database, types

I'm trying to find out if `Byte` is a valid datatype in SQL Server, and if it has an equivalent. I'm not sure if there is an equivalent type for that

Comment: tinyint see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tinyint = 1 byte = 8 bits
smallint = 2 bytes = 16 bits
int = 4 bytes = 32 bits
bigint = 8 bytes = 64 bits
```

Also:

```
char(1) = 1 byte
nchar(1) = 2 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean an eight bit integer, than TINYINT is the closest I can think of. See: [the microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql)