# What is equivalent data type for c# float in sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have Created class

```
public class UserAppearanceSettings
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string SkinName { get; set; }
    public string FontName { get; set; }
    public float FontSize { get; set; }

}
```

my sql table script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserAppearanceSettings](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[UserName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[SkinName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FontName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FontSize] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and getting error

> The 'FontSize' property on 'UserAppearanceSettings' could not be set to a 'System.Double' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.Single'.

What datatype should I use in sqlserver for Float

Comment: The .Net framework `System.Single` is mapped in SQL Server to `Real`. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings)

Comment: In your case, you should also pay attention to the **non-null value** requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be double.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Comment: Instead of answering such questions, it is better to flag or vote to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Well, yes, you are right. I am kind of new here.

Comment: I understand. That is exactly the reason I am telling you, before you get downvoted a lot.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I want to change sql datatype not C#

Comment: Then use the appropriate data type. See the duplicate referenced above your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes

Answer (score -1):

Use fluent API to instruct entity framework to behave differently than it would behave by convention. Do this in your override of DbContext.OnModelCreating.

If you want to tell entity framework that every float in your DbSet classes should have SQL Data type Float(size, d) use  [ConventionPrimitivePropertyConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.conventionprimitivepropertyconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
public override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Treat every float as SQL FloatType(53:
    modelBuilder.Properties<float>
        .Configure(floatType => floatType.HasColumnType("float(53)");

    base:OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

If you only want some float properties to have the float type use [HasColumnType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration.hascolumntype(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserAppearanceSettings>()
    .Property(setting => setting.FontSize)
    .HasColumnType("float(53)");
```