# SQL XML datatype equivalent in C# .net

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I am currently parsing the data off an XML file and storing them onto a nvarchar field on the database. I am now looking to change NVarchar to XML. I am using Code First approach on EF Core, what is the XML equivalent data type in C# .net?

Some previous queries suggest that I can use String ([C# Equivalent of SQL Server DataTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425389/c-sharp-equivalent-of-sql-server-datatypes)), but some suggest something else(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

I am looking to clarify on what's the best approach for my query where I am not manipulating the XML content, I am merely parsing a file and inserting the data into the database.

Update:

I ended up using a String on C# .net as I didn't have to do any Xml manipulation, I copied the data from a file and sent it over as a String. Below is the code I used:

```
     var doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(file.FullName);

                if (doc.FirstChild.NodeType == XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration)
                {
                    XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = (XmlDeclaration)doc.FirstChild;
                    if (String.Compare(xmlDeclaration.Encoding, Encoding.Unicode.WebName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
                    {
                        xmlDeclaration.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode.WebName;
                    }
                }
                string XmlString = doc.OuterXml;
```

Comment: The data context automatically maps XML to `XElement`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using a string directly - and especially in you case where you just need to store the data. Either go with [SqlXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqlxml.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlTypes_SqlXml__ctor_System_Xml_XmlReader_) or something else that gives a reader. For example like this:

```
var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("@xml", SqlDbType.Xml);
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
param.Value = doc.CreateReader();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(Connection and Command object left out).

The important advice here is just not to use a string object yourself, but as you have discovered already ymmv...